# Callback skipped a part

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have some trouble with my js callback, I can't understand why my callback of my function don't want execute all the code, just to give you an idea :

```
class LogsPortail {
static SetLogs(pool, req, res, callback) {
    console.log('start log ');
    var bCallBack = false;
    var now = new Date();
    var endpoint = req.originalUrl
    endpoint = endpoint.split("?")[0]
    endpoint = endpoint.replace("/", "")
    var query = "INSERT INTO LOGS_PORTAIL (ENDPOINT, TYPE, DATE_HEURE_LOGS, LOGIN) VALUE ('" + endpoint + "','" + req.method + "','" + now.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ') + "','" + 'API' + "')";
    var queryParam = "INSERT INTO LOGS_PORTAIL_PARAM (IDLOGS_PORTAIL, NOM, VALEUR) VALUE ";
    console.log('query 1 log ');
    pool.query(query, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error : " + query);
            bCallBack = true;
            callback();
        } else {
            console.log('query log 2');
            //On a bien inséré le logs portail, maintenant on ajout tous les paramètres
            for (var key in req.query) {
                if (queryParam != "INSERT INTO LOGS_PORTAIL_PARAM (IDLOGS_PORTAIL, NOM, VALEUR) VALUE ")
                    queryParam += ","
                queryParam += " (" + results.insertId + ",'" + key.toLowerCase() + "', '" + req.query[key] + "')"
            }
            for (var key in req.body) {
                if (queryParam != "INSERT INTO LOGS_PORTAIL_PARAM (IDLOGS_PORTAIL, NOM, VALEUR) VALUE ")
                    queryParam += ","
                queryParam += " (" + results.insertId + ",'" + key.toLowerCase() + "', '" + req.body[key] + "')"
            }

            pool.query(queryParam, function(err, resultsParam) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error : " + queryParam);
                    console.log(err);
                    bCallBack = true;
                    callback();
                } else {
                    bCallBack = true;
                    callback();
                }
            });

        }
    });

    while (bCallBack === false) {}
    console.log('call back end ');
    //callback();        
}
}
```

To explain you, my first query will be executed perfectly, and after that, the callback will not go through the condition but will go at the end where (for the test) I put an infinity while where my code will never exit.

This is what my log shows - we never see the logs "query log 2"

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: `while (bCallBack === false) {}` ***WILL BLOCK THE THREAD AND NOT ALLOW STUFF TO RUN***

Comment: I know, it's just for some test, i just want to see the next part of my callback work et call the callback of this fucntion

Comment: @JonathanDelean well, you cannot ***because you are blocking the callback from executing***.

Comment: Common guys, Forget this while at the, end, i dont have it, if i lets the code without the while, my code will never go in second query.
So all your answer dont help me, it dont explain (like the title say) whe my condition with my second query is never called

Comment: It might be a good idea to describe *precisely* what the problem is and supply a [mcve]. So far two problems were spotted and you claimed you don't have either of them. We are unable to guess what the real code is. We can only work on what's shown. And what you show has an issue due to an infinite loop. If that's not there, it doesn't make much sense for the execution to stop. Make sure to provide the *minimum* needed code to reproduce the problem by removing irrelevant parts, so we can diagnose this much easier.

Comment: You have an reproductible exemple, who is as minimal as possible to understand the problème, i take more than 30 minute to answer to other post and you read 1 min, say the first thing you see and dont try to think about the whole problem

Comment: The problem I can see is that the loop is blocking the thread. Therefore, the callback cannot run. You then said that's not the case because the same problem occurs without the loop. Therefore, that is extra unneeded code. Similarly everything about `bCallBack` is unneeded, same with most stuff inside. From the log you've shared, neither the error is called nor the `console.log('qury log 2');` in the success part of the callback. If *that* is the case, the only conclusion is that the callback is not executed because `pool.query(query` doesn't finish. It's hard to believe this happening.

Comment: Especially without an error of some sort. Is the query taking too long? I don't know. I *cannot* know - I neither have your DB schema, nor your data, nor the DB, driver, etc. You haven't narrowed down the problem enough - there is *some code* and you say it doesn't work. But haven't even found which The two *very obvious* problems pointed out you say weren't there. From everything I've seen, I can hardly believe this code is correct and is accurately causing showing the problem. That's all I've seen in 1 minute.

Comment: If all you've said is *accurate*, then [this will be the minumum code to reproduce the problem](https://pastebin.com/a6VZXSsF). Notice how it's a third the size of what you've posted? That is because it is *minimal*. Doesn't have needless loops, doesn't have needless code that doesn't even run. It focuses on the issue. And with *this* code the only conclusion I can make is that the database never finishes processing your query. Is that the case? I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your response, bCallBack was just to explain you mor easyly with the loop, it's not here actually, pool.query(query finish perfecly with 0.1 second, after that, the callback  is returned, all my parents process are executed and after that, my second query is executed